# Are Fock spaces just a special type of tensor algebra?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, tensor-calculus, superalgebra, clifford-algebra

Are Fock spaces just a special type of tensor algebra?

The definitions I am using:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra

From what I can tell, the similarities and differences are as follows:

Both are graded algebras, ie direct sums of grades/levels. For both, each (the nth) grade consists of $n$-fold tensor products (which correspond to rank $n$ tensors), although while for a tensor algebra it is a general tensor product, whereas for a Fock space it is either the symmetrized or anti-symmetrized tensor product. Also the vector space of a Fock space is not just any old vector space, but necessarily a Hilbert space, whereas any vector space will do for a tensor algebra. Also, for a Fock space, the direct sum is not enough; we need to take the metric space completion under the metric induced by the inner product of the underlying Hilbert space, whereas for tensor algebras we don't worry about whether the resulting object is metrically complete or not.

I suppose better analogies would be drawn between symmetrized Fock spaces and symmetric algebras and antisymmetrized Fock spaces and exterior algebras, but I wanted to somehow capture both cases, hence the reference to tensor algebras (because for tensor algebras over the real numbers, symmetric/exterior algebras can be identified with subspaces of the tensor algebra, not just quotients of the tensor algebra).

Comment: ...yes, "Fock spaces" are just the symmetric/antisymmetric parts of tensor products of the one-particle space. Is there a physics question here?

Comment: In fact the paper by Irving Segal where he introduced Fock spaces to the mathematical community are called "tensor algebras over Hilbert spaces" ;-)

Comment: @ACuriousMind I thought it was a physics question because it was about Fock spaces -- I know of them from physics before, but didn't realize there was such an elegant way to connect them before.